Mediation with Mundlak's panel model in lagged form
My model is

y(t+2) = a + b.indep_var(t) + c.indep_var_sq(t) + controls(t)

.
It is a non-linear (concave) relationship based on correlated random effects using Mundlak's approach. I need to test for mechanism design using mediation analysis.
Have checked other posts on the forum but could not find the answer as these discuss cross sectional data and not a panel data with lagged models.
Please suggest how to conduct this analysis. Thanks.
